# Can I use a gateway address on another subnet?

Tags: vmware, nat

I've some problem connecting my virtual machine to my internet. Can I use another gateway ip address other then my subnet ip address? The gateway ip address is from my router ip address? My problem is that the vmnet8 dhcp server isn't started automatically. When I want to connect my virtual machine I need to restart the vmnet8 dhcp server everytime when I start my virtual machine?

[image]

Comment: Each subnet has a gateway to the outside world. In order to communicate with anything on outside your network, you must first traverse your subnet's gateway. If you put an address in the gateway field that is not on your subnet, you will not be able to send traffic outside your network. We might be able to suggest a way around it if we knew more about your network topography (break down of subnets, routers, clients, etc).

Comment: Thanks, so it must be the same subnet. But when it's on the same subnet I can't ping the gateway? I don't have an interface for the gateway?  Or can I use the virtual interface ip address as gateway ip address? Do you suggest dhcp lease time for my problem? I need to restart the dhcp server everytime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot. The gateway IP tells the system how to get to another subnet, and without it, packets won't leave the current subnet.

A computer only knows how to talk to the other computers that are directly connected on the same subnet. A gateway is a "default route" which specifies where packets should be sent by default if they are not destined for somewhere on the local subnet.

Comment: Is there an RFC reference to back this? :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, if you define a static route to the default gateway.

This router has to be on your subnet. This doesn't make it your default gateway.

[Found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98344/does-the-gateway-have-to-be-on-the-subnet)

Comment: While this may answer the question, please be aware you have answered a question that is many years old and already has an accepted answer.

Comment: Its also possible to have some Point-to-Point Tunnel running and use this adresse as gateway.